# How rate of interest scheme in bank works?

Tags: banking, interest-rate, india, student-loan

When I was looking at SBI site, I got this info:

Loan Amount

Rate of Interest*

> For loans upto Rs.4 lacs -  3.50% above Base Rate, currently 13.50% p.a.

What does it mean? interest rate is 13.5 or 3.5? I could not understand terminology.

also it says:

> 1% concession for full tenure of the loan, if interest is serviced promptly as and when applied during the moratorium period, including course duration

what is that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The interest rate is 13.5%

The Reserve Bank of India has made it mandatory to quote all variable loans as "Base Rate + Spread". The Reserve Bank has given a guideline / formula to calculate the Base Rate. All loans should be above Base Rate. Currently the Base Rate for SBI is at 10%. So you are getting a variable rate of Interest. If the base rate changes from 10 to 11%, your interest will become 14.5%. If the base rate goes down from 10 to 9%, you rate will become 12.5%.

If you make monthly re-payments on time throughout the loan duration, then you will get a discount of 1% in the rate of interest.